# Google App Engine - Failed to generate quickstart-web.xml

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have java8 project in Google App Engine . I already deployed one version of it. Now I made some changes and trying to redeploy with same command as before:

```
mvn package appengine:deploy
```

But it always fails with message:

> Failed to generate quickstart-web.xml

Any idea what to do? I don't know what happened that it suddenly stopped working. Only thing I thought it could be was that I generated indexes for datastore inside Google Shell with .yaml file (java-11 version), so it somehow messed up, but I am not really sure.

The log looks like this

```
com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AdminException: Unable to stage app: Failed to generate quickstart-web.xml.
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.stageApplication(AppAdminImpl.java:543)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.stageApplicationWithDefaultResourceLimits(AppAdminImpl.java:492)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg$StagingAction.execute(AppCfg.java:2508)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.executeAction(AppCfg.java:363)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.<init>(AppCfg.java:211)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.<init>(AppCfg.java:118)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.main(AppCfg.java:114)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to generate quickstart-web.xml.
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.createQuickstartWebXml(Application.java:1732)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.populateStagingDirectory(Application.java:1002)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.createStagingDirectory(Application.java:862)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.stageApplication(AppAdminImpl.java:539)
... 6 more
```

Comment: Could you please share your quickstart-web.xml file? And could you please share the version of gcloud SDK? ( You can see it running the following command in Cloud Shell: gcloud --version )

Comment: gcloud --version
Google Cloud SDK 284.0.0
app-engine-java 1.9.78
app-engine-python 1.9.88
bq 2.0.54
cloud-datastore-emulator 2.1.0
core 2020.03.06
gsutil 4.48


About quickstart - I dont have one, I thought it will be generated automatically as it said "Failed to generate quickstart-web.xml". What do I need it for?

Comment: @NibrassH maybe you could help me with this too? This question about xml file is when I use java8 , the other when using java11.. I was not able to make it work either way.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60674632/gae-no-api-environment-is-registered-for-this-thread

Comment: Are you using App Engine Standard Environment or Flexible?

Comment: I believe I'm using standard environment, not sure what was chosen at the beggining. I tried java 8 and java 11, both xml and yaml configurations. It's a project I inherited after a guy and I exported sources from deployed, compiled app, so not a good one :)

Comment: Could you please share your project structure ? Please explain what are you trying to do. The quickstart-web.xml or pom.xml file is not generated automatically, you have to create it according your needs. You can follow this [App Engine Java 8 Official Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/building-app/environment-setup?hl=no) .

Comment: I know how maven works I am just confused about the quickstart-web.xml :) I'll try to generate new project with the official documentation and see what is in quickstart-web.xml. I found out that there was some quickstart-web.xml file in the old project but it still did not work after putting it there.
quickstart-web.xml is here
https://pastebin.com/wRpTQuCZ

and the structure https://imgur.com/a/izwL1VZ but I wonder why does the message says Failed to **generate** if it should be created by me. Than it should be something like malformed quickstart-web.xml. Then I'd knew fault is on my side

Comment: The error message failed to generate is caused when the deploy command doesn't find any pom.xml or quick-start.xml file.Are you able to launch your project locally? Could you please share you app.yaml file?

Comment: When using java11 configuration, I am able to start app localy through spring boot, then , the controllers that don't query google datastore work fine, but when trying to get some data , it ends up with "No api environment is registered for this thread." The same error is thrown when app is deployed to gcloud, where I thought there would be api environemnt configured, altgough I did not find any info what it means. here is app.yaml https://pastebin.com/daCXbP3i the weird thing is, I managed to make it work ONCE after deploying to GAE (I got data from DB) but trying to redeploy failed :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209801/discussion-between-martin-svoava-and-nibrass-h).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To migrate from Java8 project to Java11 in App Engine Standard, you can follow the next [Official Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/java-differences).